# Finding the range for an Extreme Value!

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How does one find the range of

$xy+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$

I know the domain is $\mathbf |R^2$ except $(0,0)$.

Comment: Note: The domain is $\{(x,y): x\neq 0 \land y \neq 0\}$ which is not $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick y=-1, then the function becomes f(x)=-x+1/x-1. f is continuous in (0,infinity). As x approach 0 on the positive side, f(x)->infinity. As x approach infinity, f(x)->negative infinity. Since f is conitinuous in (0,infinity), by intermediate value theorem, the range of f is all real numbers

Comment: $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$, not even when $y=-1$ is held fixed.

Comment: f doesn't have to be continuous at x=0, it just has to be continuous as it is approaching 0. To be more rigorous, given any N>1, I can pick x=1/(N+2), so that f(1/(N+2)) = 1/(N+2)+(N+2)-1>N. Thus f(x) can indeed cover any large number approaching infinity

Comment: I did edit my answer and specify that f is continuous in (0,infinity).